# Performance comparison(in the terms of heap size) whether to use collection object or Java transfer object

Tags: java, memory, collections

Which one having less performance issue (in the terms of heap size).

Whether I create `HasMap<key,value>` to get data according to it's key value 
or shall I use `transfer object` and  using its setters & getters method retrieve the data.

Here I have to create almost 1000 hashmap or transfer object  at a time .

Comment: It's not a question of performance, it's a question of proper design. A transfer object is strongly typed and you know what you're getting.

Comment: @Kayaman actually i have to create 1000 new object in a loop & a/c to key i have to store the all values.like this for(i=0i<1000;i++){new HashMap<String,String>} or for(i=0;i<1000;i++){new DataTransferObject()}.                                                         So in a loop whether create Hash map or create transfer object

Comment: As I said, it's not a question of performance.

Comment: How many objects are you putting in the hashmap and are they all the same type or not?

Comment: I have got out of memory Error: Java heap space thats why i have written performance issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transfer object is much more economical, try this test

```
public class Test1 {
    int i1 = 1;
    int i2 = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        long m0 = rt.totalMemory() - rt.freeMemory();
        Map m = new HashMap();
        m.put("i1", 1);
        m.put("i2", 1);
        //Test1 t1 = new Test1();  
        long m1 = rt.totalMemory() - rt.freeMemory();
        System.out.println(m1 - m0);
    }
}
```

it shows used memory, run it with -XX:-UseTLAB JVM arg to get correct results